# Cannot read property 'id' of undefined while update the record

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

plese check my route file `crud.js`

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var employee = require('../models/usermodel');

router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {

    var id = req.params.id;
    employee.findById(id, function (err, data) {
        res.json(data)
    });

})

router.post('/login', (req, res) => {

    // res.json(`hello ${req.params.id}`)
    // res.json(req.body.name)
    var { name, department, email, Date } = req.body;
    var newEmp = new employee();
    newEmp.name = name;
    newEmp.department = department;
    newEmp.email = email;
    newEmp.Date = Date;
    newEmp.save().then((result) => {
        res.json('added')
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
    });;
    console.log(newEmp);
})

router.put('/update/:id', (res, req) => {
  

    employee.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body,
        function (err, docs) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
            else {
                console.log("Updated User : ", docs);
            }
        });
});

router.delete("/delete/:id", function (req, res) {
    employee.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);

        }
        else {
            res.json('deleted');
        }
    });
});



module.exports = router;
```

i need help in update employee

and app.js file

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
var user = require('./routes/crud');
var app = express();

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json())


// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
// app.use(express.json());
// app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

var mongourl = "mongodb://localhost:27017/myproject'"
mongoose.connect(mongourl, { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true }, (err) => { if (!err) { console.log('conected to mongodb..') } else { console.log(err.message) } });



app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
app.use('/use', user);
// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

**postman give this error:**

```
Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at D:\EXdemo\routes\crud.js:41:43
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\EXdemo\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (D:\EXdemo\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (D:\EXdemo\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\EXdemo\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at D:\EXdemo\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at param (D:\EXdemo\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:354:14)
    at param (D:\EXdemo\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:365:14)
    at Function.process_params (D:\EXdemo\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:410:3)
    at next (D:\EXdemo\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (D:\EXdemo\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
    at router (D:\EXdemo\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\EXdemo\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (D:\EXdemo\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
    at D:\EXdemo\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (D:\EXdemo\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
```

Comment: only while i send put request it give error that id is undefined

Comment: Check your arguments in your update method. Looks like you have req and res the wrong way round